# 'Stanti così le cose' vs. 'Stando così le cose'

Tags: grammar

> - Stanti così le cose, traiamone le conseguenze.
> - Stando così le cose, traiamone le conseguenze.

Ritenete sia preferibile, o — eventualmente — corretto, 'stanti' o 'stando' lì?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ambedue sono grammaticalmente corrette. La sola differenza tra le due è la precisione temporale del contesto.

Mi spiego meglio.

In inglese o in spagnolo (lingue molto più attente nell'uso del tempo in cui l'azione si svolge), la prima si tradurrebbe:

> Given so, let us draw the consequences.
>
> Dadas estas circunstancias

Mentre la seconda:

> That being so, let us draw the consequences.
>
> Siendo ese el caso

Secondo il mio parere in italiano c'è meno precisione per esprimere la consequenzialità di un'azione rispetto ad un'altra. Quindi, per essere pignoli userei *Stanti* per esprimere la contemporaneità, e *Stando* per esprimere l'anteriorità dell'azione.

Ma attenzione, nell'uso quotidiano della lingua è meno probabile ascoltare *Stanti*, mentre non mi sorprenderebbe ascoltare tale espressione in un contesto formale quale per esempio uno studio notarile o un tribunale.

---

---

**Aggiornamento**

***Stanti:*** Il participio (presente) è un modo verbale molto vicino all'aggettivo e al sostantivo. Deve il suo nome al fatto che partecipa. Fonte: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participio

***Stando:*** Il gerundio è un modo della lingua italiana utilizzato per indicare un processo considerato nei suoi riferimenti ad un secondo avvenimento. Fonte: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundio

---

Il participio presente può essere usato come aggettivo o può concordare in genere e numero con il sostantivo a cui si riferisce. Questa è una struttura molto potente, perché permette di abbreviare frasi relative (un bambino che scrive - un bambino scrivente). Il participio presente può sostituire una frase in merito perché può concordare in genere e numero con il sostantivo esatto.

Il gerundio in merito non può essere usato come frase relativa, perché il gerundio è invariabile e non può concordare con un sostantivo. Sia in spagnolo che in italiano il participio presente è scomparso come sistema produttivo (non si può formare il participio presente di qualsiasi verbo). In tedesco e inglese è del tutto normale sostituire una frase relativa ad un participio presente ed anche in francese, una lingua romanza, è possibile in determinate condizioni.

Fonte: http://www.curso-de-italiano.de/gramatica/capitulo13/13_3_5_participio_presente.htm

Comment: La domanda è stata scritta in italiano. Stanti così le cose, dovresti rispondere in italiano. Si veda [qui](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/a/6/224) riguardo la consenso su questo.

Comment: Che c'entra Google Translate?

Comment: Non so abbastanza lo spagnolo, ma ritengo che il sistema di tempi (passati, trapassati etc.) e modi dell'italiano non manchi di precisione nella descrizione delle azioni e loro successione. E personalmente – ma sarà una mia mancanza – non capisco in cosa “stando” dovrebbe denotare un'anteriorità rispetto a “stanti”.

Comment: L'utilizzo della lingua manca di precisione, non la lingua in sé.

Comment: Che significa che inglese e spagnolo sono "più attente nell'uso dei tempi in cui l'azione si svolge"? Puoi argomentare?

Comment: Non sono un esperto della materia, ma stavo pensando all'uso del Past Perfect Continuous o Progressive, cioè quando un'azione non ha più relazione con il presente: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html. In Italiano (come in Spagnolo) abbiamo la tendenza ad usare il passato senza dare importanza alla relazione degli effetti posteriori dell'azione.